# Zooming in and out in Grid, Images on WinRT (Metro style app)

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to implement something in my app, I need to show an image, and let the user pinch in and out of the images.

I think its possible using the ScrollViewer, but I couldnt get it to work, help?

Comment: I think what you're describing is what is called "Semantic Zoom", you might have some luck searching for that.

Comment: @LarryOsterman No. Semantic zoom is a concept that uses two (or more) levels of detail for each piece of content instead of just graphically scaling it down. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465319.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to oversimplify this, but the WinRT XAML ScrollViewer has gesture manipulation built in.

You can see what I mean [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoommode.aspx). This might not be what you want. But it's sure a simple approach and might fit a certain % of scenarios. Maybe even yours.

> Controls that incorporate a ScrollViewer in compositing often set a value for ZoomMode in the default template and starting visual states, and it is this templated value that you will typically start with. Controls with a ScrollViewer as part of their composition typically use template binding such that setting the attached property at the level of the control will change the scroll behavior of the ScrollViewer part within the control. Otherwise, it may be necessary to replace the template in order to change the scroll behavior of a ScrollViewer part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried that, but you can not zoom in to a point from code behind. To clarify the idea, am building an indoor map, and i want to highlight and zoom in to some areas.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Morten Nielsen's article on [Building A Multi-Touch Photo Viewer Control](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control.aspx). It's for Silverlight/Windows Phone, but if you just enable manipulations on the image and change a few types in manipulation events - it should work great.

A simple solution that might be enough for you is to just put the image in a ScrollViewer, although to see it working - you need a touch screen or run it in a simulator (use the pinch tool, then drag and scroll on the image to zoom in/out).

You can also zoom it with code:

```
<Grid
    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="myScrollViewer">
        <Image
            Source="/Assets/SplashScreen.png" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

.

```
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myScrollViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled; // default
    Test();
}

private async void Test()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (double x = 0; x < 2 * Math.PI; x += Math.PI / 30)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 / 30);
            float factor = (float)(1.0 + Math.Sin(x) / 10);
            myScrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(factor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one, it didnt work well for me. I couldnt port it. And I think there's an easier method to do it, I saw someone did it before, but that was in some workshop, I cant contact that guy.